# Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution with SpringBoot + Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I am creating a Spring Boot application with DB PostgreSQL. My `application.properties` looks as follow:

```
## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my-db
spring.datasource.username= myusername
spring.datasource.password= mypassword

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

The dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Simple Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "questions")
@Data
public class Question {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "question_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "question_generator",
            sequenceName = "question_sequence",
            initialValue = 1000
    )
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 3, max = 100)
    private String title;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    private String description;
}
```

The Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface QuestionRepository extends JpaRepository<Question, Long> {
}
```

And the Controller:

```
@RestController
public class QuestionController {

    @Autowired
    private QuestionRepository questionRepository;

    @GetMapping("/questions")
    public Page<Question> getQuestions(Pageable pageable) {
        return questionRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }
}
```

When I tried to run the application, it threw an error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to
> open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
>
> Caused by:
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This ResultSet is closed.

Can someone give me a tipp what did I make wrong in the configuration? Thank you so much in advanced!

Comment: We'll need to see the full stacktrace.